# Редактирование файла на сервере php

Tags: php, html, css, apache, xampp

Ребята, столкнулся с такой весьма странной проблемой: открываю, например, css файл на сервере (xampp) в папке htdocs с помощью любого редактора ( у меня sublimе), редактирую его,сохраняю, открываю php файл со страничкой в гугле, но никакие изменения в дэвтулсе не видны, как будто я ничего туда и не писал. С чем это может быть связано ? На всякий случай, win 10.

Comment: браузеры кэшируют файлы и не перекачивают их, если они изменились.

Answer (score 2):

Ctrl+F5 Перезагрузка страницы со сбросом кэша браузера

Answer (score 1):

Браузер кеширует файлы скриптов и стилей. Их можно обновить нажав ctrl+f5, но посетители сайта об этом не знают и сайт для них выглядеть по старому или вообще сломанным. Решить данную проблему можно добавив GET параметр к ссылке на файл там где он подключается на странице. Это заставит браузер скачать файл по новой, ведь для него это другая ссылка и другой файл и при этом сам GET параметр никак не повлияет на работу.

```
    <link href="css/app.css?v=1" rel="stylesheet">
```

Для того что-бы не менять параметр всякий раз когда вы вносите изменения в файл вы можете менять версию автоматически. В простейшем виде это:

```
    <link href="css/app.css?v=<?=filemtime(css/app.css);?>" rel="stylesheet">
```

Функция filemtime() возвращает время последнего изменения файла и при каждом сохранении у Вас будет новая ссылка на файл. то-же самое касается файлов скриптов.

Answer (score 0):

Чаще всего это кэширование, попробуйте посмотреть изменения в другом браузере.